# Annualized Return vs CAGR of Investment

Tags: investing, rate-of-return

I am a bit confused by the the two terms 'Annualized Return' and 'CAGR' (compounded annual growth rate). The definition for annulized return is [here](https://www.fool.com/knowledge-center/how-to-calculate-an-annual-return-with-stock-price.aspx). The definiton for CAGR I have taken from [here](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/cagr.asp). My understanding was that they are both same, however, the formulaes dont look same, I am a bit confused. So here is the question:

Can someone kindly explain the difference between Annualized Return vs. CAGR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between Annualized Return and CAGR.

Your first link states

```
Simple Return = (Current Price-Purchase Price) / Purchase Price
Annual Return = (Simple Return +1) ^ (1 / Years Held)-1
```

and the second link states

[image]

These two formulae are equivalent.

Simple Return +1 is the same as Ending Value / Beginning Value.

Comment: Ah, now I get it, (Current Price-Purchase Price) / Purchase Price +1 = (Current Price-Purchase Price + Purchase Price) / Purchase Price = Current Price/Purchase Price, the formulaes are indeed same, thaks a lot for clearing it up, appreciate it.